# Unity resolves WCFServiceClient and closing the WCFServiceclient

Tags: unity-container, wcfserviceclient

We are using unity to resolve the WCFService and the good practice of WCF says close the client once done.

But if we are using unity when and how to close WCFServiceClient?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that unity provides a proxy to you? Can you use a using statement on the get from unity?

```
using(var proxy = GetProxyFromUnit()){
   ...
}
```

Type of thing?